# Is there any kind of distance measurement metric that does not satisfy the triangle principle?

Tags: metric-spaces, convex-analysis, uniform-spaces, measurement-theory

Firstly I am not sure if the definition of "the triangle principle" is used correctly.

What I actually want to express is, in a 3D space, if point $\mathbf{X}$ is an interior point of some other points $\mathbf{X}_1, \mathbf{X}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{X}_m$ (points $\mathbf{X}_i, i=1,2,\cdots,m$ are vertices of a convex hull which contains $\mathbf{X}$), then is there any distance measurement metric under which the relationship $$\mathrm{dist}(\mathbf{X}_0, \mathbf{X})\le\operatorname*{\mathrm{max}}_{i=1}^{m}\{\mathrm{dist}(\mathbf{X}_0, \mathbf{X}_i)\}$$ is not satisfied?

Apparently under some homogenous distance metric, e.g. Euclidean distance, this relationship will always be true, but what if under other non-homogenous metric? Like [CIEDE2000 color difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIEDE2000)? in which the distance between two points in XYZ color space is position-dependent, since the XYZ space is not uniform for human's color perception.

So, under a non-homogenous distance measurement metric, how to prove the above relationship is satisfied or not?

Many thanks to your all.

Comment: The Triangle Inequality is one of the defining properties of a distance metric

Comment: I'd have to stop to check whether your definition is the Triangle Inequality

Comment: Properties of distance metrics include positiveness, d(A, B) = d(B, A), and triangle inequality.

Comment: Check out Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)

Comment: Yes, I know that "the triangle principle" may be incorrect for what I want to express, but I really do not know that mathematical definition.

Comment: Well, when you say "distance metric", most people will assume you are talking about an object with a bunch of properties (mentioned in Wikipedia), of which triangle inequality is one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So should I change "distance metric" to "difference quantification" or something else?

Comment: You could define a "distance" function however you want and violate any property you like. But there are good reasons that the triangle inequality is part of the definition of a metric.

Comment: By the way, all you have to do to violate the triangle property is just say: call $d(x,y)$ the distance between two points and define $d(0,2)=3$ and $d(0,1)=1$, $d(1,2)=1$. Voila.

Comment: @ElliotG I am not going to struggle with the difinition of distance function. I just want to know that given a distance meansurement function, can I prove the triangle inequality is satisfied or not.

Comment: @jqx1991 I think your question is interesting. Do you know whether the inequality holds for CIEDE2000 color difference?

Comment: If your question is how to prove whether the triangle inequality is true for a given metric, then unfortunately we can't help. It depends entirely on the distance function, and some are significantly harder to prove than others. The color question is interesting and I have no idea. This may be a question for a computer scientist.

Comment: @JackyChong Do you mean the CIEDE2000 color difference is nonuniform? I know that but since it's the latest and most popular color difference formula, I think it's OK to regard it as a standard.

Comment: @ElliotG Yes this is exactly what I want to express. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I don't know whether it is uniform or nonuniform.

Comment: @JackyChong Sorry I misunderstanded your question. I am not sure whether the inequality in XYZ space holds for CIEDE2000 color difference, but intutively I think it holds.